# How do I transform my search form so that on enter it simply redirects users to what they wrote?

Tags: html, search, forms

I want to transform the searchform so that when an user clicks enter it simply redirects him to http://chusmix.com/`text<what he searched for>`

I want to do this so I can add some extra tags in the search form without the user knowing.

This is the code I use to display the search form:

```
<li id="search-10" class="widget_search">
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/">
    <div>
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" style="margin-left:418px;">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar">
    </div>
    </form></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How do you mean you want to do this without the user knowing?  As in, hiding the params?

Comment: @Igs: The OP is asking how to submit to `http://chusmix.com/searchtext` instead of standard `http://chusmix.com?s=searchtext`.

Comment: I mean that if I just redirect the user to http://chusmix.com/searchtext I can add extra text sorrounding searchtext like for example if he searched pizza I could add the word restaurant next to it on the href and the user would never know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript.

```
<form action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="window.location = action + s.value; return false;">
    <input name="s">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi BalusC I don't know where I can add the "extra text" to the link. I want it to redirect to: whatheusertyped+extratext where do I write it?

Comment: Also is there a way to make it have the same class of my search function so it looks the same? If not it doesn't matter I'll just style it myself

Comment: Just append it to the location. `window.location = action + s.value + '+extratext'`. As to the style, it's up to you. It was not part of the concrete problem, so I omitted all disturbing noise in the code example in my answer so that I end up with the *minimal working example*.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll figure out the rest.